# Using it++ with cmake ( QT )

Tags: c++, qt4, makefile, cmake

I have a IT++ Project for implementing Turbo Codes which works fine with the Makefile.
I have another C++ project which I am developing in QT.

I plan to integrate both. What changes I need to make in the *project.pro file.

What additional FLAGS or VARIABLES need to be set ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if links below would be helpful:

[Using CMake to Build Qt Projects](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects)

[cmake for Qt 4](http://qtnode.net/wiki/Qt4_with_cmake)

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Thanks, I made some changes in the .bashrc file and included the libraries in the Project pro file and it worked. Thanks for your help